# Load a XAML page in another XAML page

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need some help on a Windows Phone 8 app I am currently working on.
On the left side, I want a menu, if I click an item, I need to land on the corresponding page.

When the app opens, I see this menu and a bit of the next page.
I can switch between the menu and the full page with a button in the corner.

So far, so good.. I was able to build this and code a news page on the right to test this.
But then.. if I need to load another page, I'm in trouble, because my design at this moment
is a single XAML page that scrolls.

My question is this: Is there a way to load a XAML page in another XAML page?
Will this work with bindings?

Another option would be to put all the XAML for all menu items in place and only show
the things I need for a certain menu item (that feels quite wrong).

Or am I totally missing something?

All help would be very much appreciated, as I'm a new to developing for Windows Phone.
I added a simple drawing, which I hope can explain what I'm trying to.

[image: Drawing]

Comment: I think you can make navigations. why are u trying to load another page? And if you want so, make a page into user control and you can implement what you are trying.

Comment: You can use Usercontrols to load another Xaml Page in a Xaml page.

Comment: Hey max, because otherwise I have to make a page for each menu item with the menu included I guess? The idea is to load the selected page on the right and keep the menu in place

Answer (score 0):

You can add controls in c#.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
public partial class SomePage: PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public SomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(new TextBlock()
        {
            Name = "MyTextBlock",
            Text = App.ViewModel.Item[0].SomeProperty
        });
    }
}
}
```